# printbibliography title keeps repeating

Tags: biblatex

I have an issue with printbibliography, it keeps putting the title "Reference" in all bibliography section pages to the left of the page.

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}
\printbibliography[title={Reference}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please post a small complete code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The second page (p.58) has a running head, which is the same as the title of the chapter.  (You should have similar headings at the top of all previous pages of regular text.  It's possible to remove the header, but do you really want to?

Comment: `\pagestyle{plain}` before `\printbibliography`  solve your issue, but instead of remove the header (not a good idea for a book) , consider change the format to distinguish more clearly the header and main text: Header not capitalized, more space below the header,  use a different font type/size, ...a 0.4 pt rule, header text in gray (or some other non-distracting color, ...), etc.

Comment: You should see the same effect for all `\chapter`s in your document.

Comment: Any news here? It isn't quite clear to me what you are asking: Do you want to know why the header appears? Do you want to get rid of the header for all chapters? Do you want to get rid of the header only for the bibliography? In order to be able to help you properly we also need to know which document class and which header/footer packages you are using (the solutions may differ between the standard class, the standard classes with `fancyhdr`, KOMA-Script classes and `memoir`.)